# How to bind html to an external component? (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have consumed an external library with components we would like to use, one of the components is an alert modal, that is represented as so:

```
<alert dismissible="false">Enter your text here</alert>
```

It renders out:

```
<alert dismissible="false" initialized="true">
  <div class="alert-inside alert-type-info" aria-hidden="false" role="alert">
    <div region-container="content">
      <span>
        <span class="ng-binding ng-scope">Enter your text here</span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</alert>
```

The way we have built our angular app we are using config variables to hold our content

```
AppConfig.EnterText= "Enter your text here";
```

In which case we would call alert as so

```
<alert dismissible="false">{{AppConfig.EnterText}}</alert>
```

The problem is we actually want to use some html markup to be put into the alert...

```
AppConfig.EnterText= "<strong>Notice:</strong> Enter your text here";
```

In which case, if we include the content between the tags, it will render the tags instead of processing them. I have tried

```
<alert dismissible="false" ng-bind-html="AppConfig.EnterText"></alert>
```

This results in the inner tags being replaced with the content...

```
<alert dismissible="false" initialized="true">
   <strong>Notice:</strong> Enter your text here
</alert>
```

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, I believe you need to use ng-bind-html directive in conjunction with the $sce service. Have you tried injecting the $sce service into your controller? Once you do that, you can set your variable like this:

```
AppConfig.EnterText= $sce.trustAsHtml("<strong>Notice:</strong> Enter your text here");
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue with the following:

```
<alert dismissible="false">
  <span ng-bind-html="AppConfig.EnterText"></span>
</alert>
```